# How to model time-varying correlation

Tags: time-series, correlation, modeling, finance

Suppose I have two time-series variables, $\{x_t\}$ and $\{y_t\}$, where $t\in[1,T]$.  I would like to model the correlation $\rho(x_t,y_s)$ as some function of $t$,$s$, and the difference $t-s$.  In other words, $\rho_{t,s}$ may take on a different value for any valid combination of $(t,s)$, a total of $\frac {T(T+1)}2$ correlations, but I would like to economize on the number of estimated correlations (as well as possibly improving the output) by applying some sort of model.

In the actual application I have in mind, these are macroeconomic and/or financial variables.  The derived correlations are used to derive a full pseudo-correlation matrix, which is transformed into the nearest true P.S.D. correlation matrix using [Higham's (2002)](http://imajna.oxfordjournals.org/content/22/3/329.abstract) algorithm.

Comment: Can you give an idea of the size of the dataset (i.e. T=?,S=?)? Is there a reason why you don't model the time varying correlation matrix directly (DCC garch)?

Comment: @user603 T is the same for both x and y, and it is about 600.  Furthermore, there are about 30 such variables, and I need pairwise correlation between each of them.  I am not familiar with DCC GARCH, I will look into it.  However, the idea here is to find a correlation between $x$ at time $t$ and $y$ at time $s$ (not both at $t$).

Comment: 30 is a bit larger than what i had in mind and probably too large for DCC to work (tough numerical rountines may have improved, check the package http://rgarch.r-forge.r-project.org/). Indeed, a matrix reconstrution approach as in Higham's may be best here.

Comment: I don't think DCC is what you want since it looks like you're asking for constant correlation coefficients? $\big($By the fact that you didn't specify $\rho(x_t,y_s)(t)$, $\rho(x_t,y_s)_t$ or $\rho_t(x_t,y_s)$ $\big)$.

Answer (score -2):

It may be a little bit late for you, but for future readers. I think what you are looking for is some sort of cross-correlation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.